# Smallest algebra containing a function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, solution-verification

**The question**

> Let $f: X \to \Bbb C$, then what is the smallest algebra $\mathcal{A}$ containing $f$?

**My attempt**

I claim that:
$$\mathcal{A} = \{\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} a_i f^i : [n \in \Bbb N, a_i \in \Bbb C]\}$$
In fact, it is clear that the set thus defined is an algebra (closure under addition and multiplication by a scalar can be proved directly while closure under multiplication may be proved considering two sums of degrees $m$ and $n$ and by proceeding by induction on $n$, after having fixed $m$). Moreover, every function in $\mathcal{A}$ can be constructed using only $f$, therefore every algebra containing $f$ must also include $\mathcal{A}$.

I would like to know if this answer is correct and satisfactory.

---

As always, any comment or answer is welcome and let me know if I can explain myself clearer!

Comment: @Surb I am sorry, I have yet to be introduced to such concepts. So far my definition of algebra of functions on a set is the one given in Chapter 7 of Rudin's "Principle of Mathematical Analysis", that is, a collection of functions closed under addition, multiplication and multiplication by a scalar.

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the solution is correct.
$$
\mathcal{A}=\mathbb{L}_{\mathbb{C}}\{f^i, i\in\mathbb{N}\}
$$
where $\mathbb{L}_{\mathbb{C}}$ is the linear span with complex coefficients. As you have said, this is an algebra and any other algebra containing $f$ must contain $f^i$ and thus, $\mathcal{A}$.